# Поиск в коллекции List по нескольким значениям

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

Как сравнить эти List и записать разные строки в list3. Например если хотя бы одно значение не совпадает оно записывается в list3 вся строка где есть различия. Например первая строка List1 = 1.2.3.4 а List2 = 1.2.3.5 т.к. в них есть отличия то эта строка идет в list3. Если строки равны то они пропускаются.

```
public class DB
{
    public string v { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
    public string u { get; set; }
    public string е { get; set; }
}
List<DB> list1 = new List<DB>();
List<DB> list2 = new List<DB>();
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Начните с того, что напишите метод Equals для своего класса.

Comment: И непонятно вы попарно хотите элементы сравнить в двух списках или что-то другое?

Comment: Например первая строка List1 = 1.2.3.4 а List2 = 1.2.3.5 т.к. в них есть отличия то эта строка идет в list3. Если строки равны то они пропускаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жмем на название класса, сбоку появится [image: img1], жмем на нее и выбираем "Создать Equals и GetHashCode..."

[image: menu]

Далее откроется окно, в котором нам предложат выбрать те объекты, которые будут проверятся:

[image: generate]

После всей этой процедуры, в классе будут созданы дополнительные методы (`Equals` и `GetHashCode`), которые послужат для сравнения двух классов. Я добавлю еще конструктор для удобства и в итоге класс будет выглядеть так (P.S. Ужасные наименования!!):

```
public class DB
{
    public DB(string v, string o, string u, string e)
        => (this.v, this.o, this.u, this.e) = (v, o, u, e);

    public string v { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
    public string u { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is DB dB && v == dB.v && o == dB.o && u == dB.u && e == dB.e;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = 1452423071;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(v);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(o);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(u);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(e);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Теперь дело за малым, нам остается вызвать методы, которые сравнят объекты в коллекциях и вернут результат ([Distinct, Union, Except и Intersect](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level2/2_9.php)):

```
var list1 = new List<DB>
{
    new DB("0", "1", "2", "3"),
    new DB("4", "5", "6", "7")
};

var list2 = new List<DB>
{
    new DB("1", "1", "2", "3"),
    new DB("4", "5", "6", "7")
};

var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

После этого в `result` у нас будет 1 объект, `DB("0", "1", "2", "3")`.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо за помощь!! Более детального ответа я не находил. Спасибо за проделанную работу и время!!